¿Como puedo hacer que mi menu mande a las actvitys correspodientes?
Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Android Studio y he implementado un menú de navegación lateral utilizando NavigationView junto con DrawerLayout. Sin embargo, al hacer clic en los elementos del menú, como "Cerrar sesión" o al intentar navegar a otras actividades, no sucede nada. He revisado mi código y no puedo identificar el problema. ¿Alguien podría ayudarme a solucionar este problema? Adjunto mi código a continuación para su revisión:
 import android.content.Intent
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.view.LayoutInflater
    import android.view.MenuItem
    import android.view.View
    import android.widget.TextView
    import android.widget.Toast
    import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle
    import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat
    import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    import com.example.pruebas.LoginActivity.Companion.userEmail
    import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
    
    
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    
        private lateinit var drawer: DrawerLayout
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    
            initToolbar()
            initNavigationView()
        }
    
    
        private fun initToolbar() {
            val toolbar: androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_main)
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    
            drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
            val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar,
                R.string.tituloappbarr, R.string.navigation_drawer_close
            )
    
            drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle)
    
            toggle.syncState()
    
        }
    
        private fun initNavigationView() {
            var navigationView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
    
            var headerView: View =
                LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.nav_header_main, navigationView, false)
            navigationView.removeHeaderView(headerView)
            navigationView.addHeaderView(headerView)
    
            var tvUser: TextView = headerView.findViewById(R.id.tvUser)
            tvUser.text = userEmail
        }
    
        fun callsignOut(view: View) {
            signOut()
        }
    
        private fun signOut() {
            userEmail = ""
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
            startActivity(Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java))
        }
    
    
        override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    
            when (item.itemId){
                R.id.nav_inicio -> callInicioActivity()
                R.id.nav_cerrarSesion -> signOut()
                R.id.nav_buscarRuta -> callBuscarRuta()
                R.id.nav_cuenta -> callCuenta()
                R.id.nav_saldo -> callSaldo()
                R.id.nav_descuento -> callDescuento()
                R.id.nav_sobreNosotros -> callSobreNosotros()
            }
    
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    
            return true
        }
        private fun callInicioActivity(){
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        private fun callBuscarRuta(){
            val intent = Intent(this, BuscarRuta::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        private fun callCuenta(){
            val intent = Intent(this, Cuenta::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        private fun callSaldo(){
            val intent = Intent(this, Saldo::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        private fun callDescuento(){
            val intent = Intent(this, Descuento::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        private fun callSobreNosotros(){
            val intent = Intent(this, SobreNosotros::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

   

Problemas específicos:
1.Los elementos del menú no responden cuando se hace clic.
2.La actividad no se abre al hacer clic en los elementos del menú.
3.¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto para que la navegación del menú funcione correctamente?
¡Agradezco cualquier ayuda que puedan brindarme para resolver este problema!

Hola. ¿Has depurado tu código? Por ejemplo, si pones un punto de interrupción en esta línea when (item.itemId){, ¿qué valor tiene ahí item.itemId?
